# How to get the latest modified file in a directory with Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, model

Is there any method in Cakephp that is able to return the latest modified file in a directory? I have tried with `$this->System->getLatestModifiedFile()` in Cakephp Model but got `Call to a member function getLatestModifiedFile() on a non-object` error.

Thanks for advice there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html and look for `File::lastChange()` in File API section. This might help.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to cakephp file and folder API, i managed to use `File::lastChange()` method to solve my issue. Thanks for the help there. Here's an example:

```
App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
App::uses('File', 'Utility');
$file = new File('/tmp/test.txt');
//the following will return an epoch time, can be formatted by date method
echo $file->lastChange();
```